# issue with setCustomValidity

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a simple if statement to test whether the passwords in each input boxes match. If they both match, no error is given and if they do not match the error "they do not match" is given using .setCustomValidity(). The issue I am having is when the error is given and then the passwords are corrected to match, the error is still given. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Below is my code and a link to a working JSfiddle.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1934foej/

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input id="first" type="text" min="16" max="100" placeholder="New password" autofocus required>
</label>
<label>
    <input id="second" type="text" min="16" max="100" placeholder="Repeat password" required>
</label>

<input id="submit" type="submit">
```

JS:

```
var firstPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#first');
var secondPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#second');
var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');


submit.onclick = function () {
    var firstPassword = firstPasswordInput;
    var secondPassword = secondPasswordInput; 

    //checks for match
    if( firstPassword.value !== secondPassword.value) {
        firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity("they do not match");
        } 
}
```

Comment: @ImranAli there is no typo in the operator, `!==` is a valid js equality operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are doing is the customValidity remains `"they do not match"` because you are not setting it to empty string (which the browser takes it as successful validation), so the input remains with the same state after one unsuccessful validation.

```
submit.onclick = function() {

    // there is no need to redefine these two variables
    var firstPassword = firstPasswordInput;
    var secondPassword = secondPasswordInput;    

    if(firstPassword.value !== secondPassword.value) {
        firstPassword.setCustomValidity("they do not match");
    }
    //add this part
    else {
        firstPassword.setCustomValidity("");
    }

}
```